# Why O(2^log(n)) = O(n) and it is not a exponential run time?

Tags: math, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Why is `O(2^log(n))` equivalent to `O(n)`?  Also why is this considered as an exponential run time and not a polynomial run time?

Comment: Is the `log` in your expression base 2?  `O(n)` is linear run time, not exponential.

Comment: Because algebra. Read the definition of a logarithm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement is sometimes true and sometimes false depending on the base of the logarithm. Examples:

- *O*(2<sup>lg *n*</sup>) = *O*(*n*), where lg is the binary logarithm.
- *O*(2<sup>log_4 *n*</sup>) = *O*(*n*<sup>1/2</sup>), where log_4 is the logarithm to base 4.
- *O*(2<sup>log_1.25992 *n*</sup>) = *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup>), because 1.25992 is the cube root of 2.

In general, *O*(2<sup>log *n*</sup>) for an unspecified logarithm base is equal to *O*(*n*<sup>*k*</sup>) for some *k* (which is **polynomial time**).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense but could you show me the algebra part of it? Haven't learned much about logs :P

Comment: @user2180617 A logarithm is the inverse of an exponential. Think of it as the number that goes in the power spot if you were trying to figure out what exponent of `2` would equal `n` (in the scenario of the log having a base of `2`). Based on the definition, a bunch of proofs and rules come into play, demonstrated by Nayuki's answer.

Comment: in math, lg is often used for log10

Comment: Perhaps, but this is a computer science environment here. Most CS textbooks and algorithm papers use lg to mean base 2, heh.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Sure, but base 10 is useless to computers, unless electrical signals somehow have developed into having 10 different states instead of 2. Base 10 is also useless to most other Engineering problems, so we use `ln` instead (base of `e`)

Answer (score 0):

2 ^ log2(n) = n for log2, which is what log(n) means for performance characteristics (big O).

It is O(n), and hence polynomial (n is polynomial), not exponential (2^n would be exponential).